# auto scroll page handling with ruby, nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

While using `xpath` and `nokogiri` for crawling pages, I encountered some problems with auto-scrolling
Most of auto-scrolling usually have some kinds of paginations so that I can handle by make input.

However, if like this page if autoscroll exists as js function, how can I try to crawl?

Comment: Since Nokogiri is XML/HTML parser and not a headless browser, you can't perform the autoscroll option in js, either you have to find the api being triggered in scroll and take advantage of it or you should use some kinda selenium driver I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when autoscroll is used, js function performs AJAX request to server to fetch new items. So you can just open browser inspector and check XHR requests that are being made why you scroll the page.

For example, this juswatch performs request

```
    https://apis.justwatch.com/content/titles/en_US/popular?body=%7B%22age_certifications%22:null,%22content_types%22:null,%22genres%22:null,%22languages%22:null,%22max_price%22:null,%22min_price%22:null,%22monetization_types%22:%5B%22flatrate%22,%22rent%22,%22buy%22,%22ads%22,%22free%22%5D,%22page%22:2,%22page_size%22:30,%22presentation_types%22:null,%22providers%22:null,%22release_year_from%22:null,%22release_year_until%22:null,%22scoring_filter_types%22:null%7D
```

So to parse the whole site, you don't need nokogiri at all. Just perform requests above, each time replacing the page parameter and parse returning json.